# Webpack 2 Configuration Error

Tags: javascript, build, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

Im not certain what Im doing wrong, would appreciate some insight into this configuration. I am getting the following error:

**ERROR : throw new WebpackOptionsValidationError(webpackOptionsValidationErrors)**

```
/var/www/homelyfe/hl-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:16
        throw new WebpackOptionsValidationError(webpackOptionsValidationErrors);
        ^
WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[1].use[0] should be one of these:
   string | object { loader?, options?, query? }
 - configuration.module.rules[1].use should be one of these:
   string | object { loader?, options?, query? } | [string | object { loader?, options?, query? }]
    at webpack (/var/www/homelyfe/hl-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:16:9)
    at processOptions (/var/www/homelyfe/hl-app/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js:310:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/homelyfe/hl-app/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js:374:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:141:18)
    at node.js:933:3
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

**MY WEBPACK CONFIGURATION FILE:**

```
const path = require("path");
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const htmlWebpackPlugin = require( "html-webpack-plugin" );
const parts = require( "./webpack.config.parts" );
const PATHS = {
    app : path.join( __dirname, "app" ),
    build : path.join( __dirname, "build" )
};
const TARGET = process.env.BUILD_DEV || process.env.BUILD_PROD;

const common = {
    entry : {
        app : PATHS.app + "/index.js"
    },
    output : {
        filename : "run.build.js",
        path : PATHS.build,
        publicPath : "/assets/"
    },
    resolve : {
        extensions : [ "js", "jsx" ]
    },
    module : {
        rules : [
            {
                test : /\.jsx?$/,
                use : [
                    {
                        loader : "babel-loader",
                        options : {
                            presets : [
                                "react",
                                "es2015"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                include : PATHS.app
            }
        ]
    }
};

var config;

switch( process.env.npm_lifecycle_event ){
    case( "buildProd" ):
        config = merge( common,
                             parts.defineENV(),
                             parts.sourceMaps( "__PROD__" ),
                             {} );
    case( "startDev" ):
    default:
        config = merge( common,
                             parts.defineENV(),
                             parts.sourceMaps( "__DEV__" ),
                             parts.devServer( PATHS.app ),
                             parts.eslint(PATHS.app, path.join( __dirname, ".eslintrc" )),
                             parts.devtool(),
                             parts.htmlWebpackPlugin( "---TESTING---" ));
};

module.exports = config;
```

Clearly, Im doing something wrong with the merge function, as notified by the error, however, the returned object appears to be fine. Here is the output of the config obj (the main webpack.config obj.):

**CONFIGURATION OUTPUT OBJECT:**

```
{
  entry:{
    app: '/var/www/homelyfe/hl-app/app/index.js'
  },
  output:{
    filename: 'run.build.js',
    path: '/var/www/homelyfe/hl-app/build',
    publicPath: '/assets/'
  },
  resolve:{
    alias:{
      assets: '/var/www/homelyfe/hl-app/app/assets',
      components: '/var/www/homelyfe/hl-app/app/components'
    },
    extensions: [ 'js', 'jsx' ]
  },
  module:{
    rules:[
      { test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use:[
          { loader: 'babel-loader',
            options : {
              presets : [
                "react",
                "es2015"
              ]
            }
          }, 
        ],
        include: '/var/www/homelyfe/hl-app/app'
      },
      { test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: [ 
          { enforce: 'pre', 
            loader: 'eslint-loader',
            query: [Object] } 
        ],
        include: '/var/www/homelyfe/hl-app/app'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: 
   [ DefinePlugin { definitions: [Object] },
     HotModuleReplacementPlugin { multiStep: true, fullBuildTimeout: 200 },
     HtmlWebpackPlugin { options: [Object] } ],
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  devServer: 
   { historyApiFallback: true,
     hot: true,
     inline: true,
     stats: 'errors-only' } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the schema that validates the config in [webpack github repo](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/schemas/webpackOptionsSchema.json#L594)

```
"ruleSet-use-item": {
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/ruleSet-loader"
    },
    {
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "loader": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/ruleSet-loader"
        },
        "options": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/ruleSet-query"
        },
        "query": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/ruleSet-query"
        }
      },
      "type": "object"
    }
  ]
}
```

And then look at your second rule

```
{ test: /\.jsx?$/,
    use: [ 
      { enforce: 'pre', 
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        query: [Object] } 
    ],
    include: '/var/www/homelyfe/hl-app/app'
}
```

You'll se that `enforce` is not part of `ruleSet-use-item`. You can only specify `loader`, `options` and `query` there

Comment: The webpack schema tip is an excellent tip. Thank you and yes, that resolved that part of the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

As you suspected, the culprit is the `merge` function. The `enforce` property is part of `rule` object. It should NOT be a property of [`UseEntry`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#useentry).

```
{ test: /\.jsx?$/,
  enforce: 'pre', 
  use: [ 
         { 
           loader: 'eslint-loader',
           query: [Object] } 
       ],
  include: '/var/www/homelyfe/hl-app/app'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.